# Git lane concept

Tags: git, egit

I am new to git and would like to know more about git lanes used for finding branches.
Git repository has a lane concept for identifying if we are in same branch or in main branch etc.

But when i checked the lane that is initialized for the 1st branch, it is set as "1" - main branch, the very next branch created is marked as "0" - 1st branch and next branch as lane "2" and then lane 3 and so on...

i am using egit2.1 in eclispe 
so i have doubt if

1. the master lane is always set as 1 on git.
2. where is the lane value set for master? is it part of egit or jgit

and do any of you have any documentation for egit development :)

### Edit:

Sorry if I didnt use exact name, i was unaware of the Class used for lane until i checked into the code for eGit

the code was found in **org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.history.CommitGraphTable**
some code that i found related to [lane defect](http://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/commit/?id=e78a17acc65a41e840a77c5b5243b199077e883c) for a google search of **git CommitGraphTable lane**

These are the classes where I found the Lane object and lane definition

eGit
org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.history.SWTCommit
org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.history.SWTCommitList.SWTLane

jGit
org.eclipse.jgit.revplot.PlotCommitList

So please tell me where the lane is being set for the master lane?

Comment: Google turns up nothing but this question for "git lane" or "egit lane". Can you be more specific or provide a resource? Is this specific to `egit`?

Comment: @pmr I think "lane" can be viewed here as a path within the graph of commits, like lanes of a road system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane), with some lanes having a particular role (like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local-express_lanes).

Comment: @VonC I really don't see the need to resort to auxiliary nomenclature and vote to close this. It really should be better specified before this can be answered.

Comment: @VonC I don't blame you :) Let's wait and see if the OP details the question.

Comment: i have updated the post please check if the question is clarified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further digging in to the code and the **Class PlotCommitList** was setting the Lane for each commit object in the commit tree.

This logic was part of Jgit logic

ya @VonC was right to on extent about **SWTCommitList**

```
 package org.eclipse.jgit.revplot;

 public class PlotCommitList<L extends PlotLane> extends
    RevCommitList<PlotCommit<L>>{
....
protected void enter(final int index, final PlotCommit<L> currCommit){
//This method contains the logic
}

....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a screenshot would help clarifying what you mean by "lane", but EGit doesn't attached an id to branches, it simply list them:

[image: Egit branches]

Same with Git, which simply records the active HEAD and the HEADS for all the branches.

---

After your edit, "lane" here refers to an [internal class SWTLane or SWTCommitList](https://github.com/eclipse/egit/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.ui/src/org/eclipse/egit/ui/internal/history/SWTCommitList.java#L96)", for managing the color of a branch.
I didn't see a specific lane set for `master`, only a query for all the right branches done in SWTCommitList in order to draw the right lanes.